# Disabling the Amazon EC2 Config Service - benefits? consequences?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What happens if I disable the Amazon EC2 Config Service on my windows instances?  Is that service required?  Are there performance benefits to disabling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?appendix-windows-config.html):

> The EC2Config service sets up and
>   initializes the instance during
>   startup, prepares the service for
>   bundling, and manages the event log.

The startup aspect is definitely necessary, and performance/memory hits should be extremely tiny.  I wouldn't consider this to be a factor if you're tweaking your server for performance.